# (Java) EOFException when reading from a Text File

Tags: java, io, eofexception

I am reading two strings and a double from a text file, but keep throwing an `EOFException`.
This is my code:

```
public static Book readBook(String pathname) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{
      DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(
                                new BufferedInputStream(
                                    new FileInputStream(fn)));
      String theTitle = dis.readUTF();
      String theAuthor = dis.readUTF();
      double thePrice = dis.readInt();
      dis.close();
      return new Book(theTitle, theAuthor, thePrice);
   }
```

Im really quite new to IO and have no idea on how to solve this exception, and throwing `EOFExecption` doesn't seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated, Cheers

EDIT: Stack Trace + File Contents

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
    at Model.readBook(Model.java:48)
    at Model.runApp(Model.java:17)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

File Contents

name
author
10.00
name2
author2
12.00

(In file they are all on seperate lines)

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? What is the message? Are any of your variables being filled in properly?

Comment: I always forget the Stack Trace :P sorry guys.

Comment: who did you _write_ the file?

Comment: I wrote it, posted above

Comment: sorry, _how_ did you write the file?

Comment: ahh ok the text file is pre-written with what you see above. the writing portion is in another class and surprisingly  works fine

Comment: Either this is not a text file or you are using the wrong API. A text file does not contain the output of `readInt(), readUTF()`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is text file, then you probably need to use Scanner:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (new FileInputStream (fn));
String theTitle = scanner.nextLine ();
String theAuthor = scanner.nextLine ();
double thePrice = scanner.nextDouble ();
return new Book(theTitle, theAuthor, thePrice);
```

The code above expects title, author and price to be on separate lines.

Comment: This is definitely the simplier way to accomplish reading a plain text file.  I'd also suggest to @Kamon241 to put each book entry on a new line.

Comment: Cheers guys, testing it now

Answer (score 0):

How is your text input formatted?  Are you specifying the length of the strings to read in the input?  My thinking is that you did not, or specified the length wrong, and are hitting the end of the file before on one of the subsequent reads.

> First, two bytes are read and used to construct an unsigned 16-bit integer in exactly the manner of the readUnsignedShort method . This integer value is called the UTF length and specifies the number of additional bytes to be read.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF()

Answer (score 0):

> I am reading two strings and a double from a text file

No you aren't. You are reading two writeUTF() results and an integer from a binary file. If it isn't a binary file, you are using the wrong code. You need to read the file line by line, split each line probably on the spaces, and parse the double using `Double.parseDouble()`. Or, use `java.util.Scanner` to make the whole thing easier.